# Возможно ли написание "небыло"?

Tags: орфография

Answer (score 4):

Нет, было - глагол, НЕ с глаголом всегда пишется раздельно. Вот НЕБЫЛЬ, НЕБЫЛИ (небылицы)- слитно.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, нет. Это действительно глагол "быть" в прош.вр. Поэтому не только "не было" пишется раздельно, но и, например, "не будет".